# Including a javascript ad within an entry?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to add a javascript within an EE entry? I wanted to use one of the new Amazon affiliate ads within a post to easily be able to present a selection of products specific to that post. But these ads are javascripts and natively that does not seem to work within an entry.

Comment: You should be able to add a textarea field and paste the javascript into it.

Comment: Do you mean add it as a permanent part of the field or when you create the entry? I tried the latter, but it didn't show up in the post.

Comment: If you add a channel field with type textarea to the channel in question you should be able to paste the javascript into the backend on each entry in that channel. You'd need to paste in the script tags as well.

Comment: I am probably being a bit dense, so apologies in advance. This channel is already setup with a textarea field, but when I tried making a new post and adding the script (including tags) together with the rest of the text of the post, only the text and not the ad came out.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'll do some testing and try to get you a better response.

Comment: Well, I got it to appear in the page source at least, but it seems to be encoding all " so that may be the issue.

Comment: Can you add an Input text field?  And add it in your template?!

Comment: I am not sure how that would help since Text Input only takes 256 characters?

Comment: Make sure you post the javescript while you are in "View Source" mode of the text area if it is the wysiwyg.  There is also, I believe, a setting in the field config that turns on or off allowing JS to be pasted in.

Comment: I am not using a wysiwyg editor, so that isn't the issue. And looking at the field config, I don't see any such option.